# How many prime numbers contain strictly increasing digits?

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, estimation

This was posed as an estimation problem - I'd be interested in both more accurate approximate methods (than my underestimate of 74 in the answer below) and a check of my exact answer (100, already verified in the comment section).

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to check all numbers with strictly increasing digits? There are (significantly) fewer than $2^9=512$ such numbers and they're (significantly) smaller than $10^9$.

Comment: There are exactly $2^9-1=511$ strictly positive integers with strictly increasing digits, because such a number is uniquely characterised by whether each digit is present or absent.

Comment: @TonyK Of course, but a large portion can immediately be discarded because they end in one of $2$, $4$, $5$, $6$ or $8$, or because the digit sum is a multiple of $3$, for example the largest number with strictly increasing digits.

Comment: The list is in http://oeis.org/A052015.  There are exactly $100$ of them

Comment: "I'd be interested in both more accurate approximate methods...." More accurate than what? Since you are keeping your methods secret, how can we know whether some other method is more accurate or not?

Comment: Please, Random: more accurate than *what*?

Answer (score 1):

I originally estimated that there would be $74$ such numbers. This was based on counting the primes with $1,2$ and $9$ digits, and for $k=3,4,…8$, observing that there are $9 \choose k$ integers with $k$ strictly increasing digits and that each has roughly a $\frac1{\log x}$ probability of being prime, which I further rounded to $\frac{1}{2.3(k-1)}$. This gave roughly $4+11+17+18+14+7+2+1+0=74$.

I believe that there are exactly $100$ such numbers. This is based on the matlab code below. Sorting again by number of digits, this was $4+11+20+26+20+13+4+2+0$—the biggest error with my approximate model seems to be in $4–6$-digit numbers.

```
n=0;
for i=1:9
    if isprime(i)==1
        n=n+1;
    end
    for j=i+1:9
        if isprime(10*i+j)==1
            n=n+1;
        end
        for k=j+1:9
            if isprime(100*i+10*j+k)==1
                n=n+1;
            end
            for l=k+1:9
                if isprime(1000*i+100*j+10*k+l)==1
                    n=n+1;
                end
                for m=l+1:9
                    if isprime(10000*i+1000*j+100*k+10*l+m)==1
                        n=n+1;
                    end
                    for o=m+1:9
                        if isprime(100000*i+10000*j+1000*k+100*l+10*m+o)==1
                            n=n+1;
                        end
                        for p=o+1:9
                            if isprime(1000000*i+100000*j+10000*k+1000*l+100*m+10*o+p)==1
                                n=n+1;
                            end
                            for q=p+1:9
                                if isprime(10000000*i+1000000*j+100000*k+10000*l+1000*m+100*o+10*p+q)==1
                                    n=n+1;
                                end
                                for r=q+1:9
                                    if isprime(100000000*i+10000000*j+1000000*k+100000*l+10000*m+1000*o+100*p+10*q+r)==1
                                        n=n+1;
                                    end
                                end
                            end    
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: My Python code also gives 100 such primes.

Comment: I've done my best to fix the layout—please check I didn't mangle anything! `Code` goes between backticks, and formulæ go between dollar signs.

Comment: If someone knows how to format the code so it displays as a highlighted block, please do. I just added a backtick at the start and another at the end.